# How to customise of trimmer in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the following code in which user can select video from gallery with a maximum size of 3 seconds. There's a trimmer if the selected video is longer than 3 seconds.

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagePickerController.delegate = self
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 3.0
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

I want make some changes if possible

1. How to change the colour of trimmer?
2. How to change the position of trimmer? Is it possible to add some margin on top or move the trimmer to bottom of the video?
3. How to change the size of trimmer?

Please help me if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

For the level of customization you are looking for, especially if you want to manipulate the sizing and margins of the existing trimmer, it is best to find an alternative implementation. GitHub is always a good starting point. Even if the library does not give you access to modify the trimmer in their API, you can always modify the source code as needed.
https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=video+picker&type=Repositories

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I actually wanted to know if apple provides such level of customization or not.